# Cancer history on environment-cancer relationship

Tags: cancer, history

I am interested to know how environment-cancer relationship knowledge has developed.
I know that all began when Muller first proved that mutation could be induced via ionizing radiation, X rays in the case, and hypothesized for the first time the role that this could have on carcinogenesis. Do you know further data and the main or most significant events that leaded from that point until the current state of the art? (like when smoking and cancer were proved related)

(all factors enhancing risk would be included in the query, as human behavioral aspects (such as diet), work environment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, "[soot wart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimney_sweeps%27_carcinoma)" was identified by Percival Pott in 1775. It is the first reported occupational cancer (it is a squamous cell carcinoma of the skin of the scrotum). It was shown in 1922 that an active ingredient of coal soot was a carcinogen. I'm not sure of an expansive, technical text on environmental cancers, but you may want to check out 
"The Emperor of All Maladies: A Biography of Cancer" which covers the origins of man's understanding of cancer starting with the ancient Greeks, progressing to mention Percival Pott, and then moving on to modern day science and medicine. This book won the Pulitzer in nonfiction a few years ago and is well worth your time.